# Convert from a list of characters "List<Character>" to an array of chars "char[]"

Tags: java, list, java-8, char, java-stream

What is a way in Java to convert from the `List<Character> list` to char array `char[] chars`.

I want this so that later I can create a `String` using `String(chars)`.
Do we have any shortcuts using `Stream`?

I see that we can convert from `List<Integer>` (Or `Double` and `Long`) to `int[]` (or `double[]` and `long[]`), but similar functionality is not available for `char` as we do not have a char equivalent for `IntStream`?

Please suggest if we have a quick way of doing this.

My current code is:

```java
new String(getCharArray(charList))
```

```java
private static char[] getCharArray(List<Character> charList) {
    char[] charArray = new char[charList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        charArray[i] = charList.get(i);
    }
    return charArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can do it (for instance) with:

`list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();`

However, if you want to have it as a `String` just do directly:

```
list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

**Detailed Answer**

> I see that we can convert from List (...) but similar functionality is not
> available for char as we do not have a char equivalent for IntStream?

Yes, because you can combine the inbuilt methods `mapToInt` and `toArray` to get the conversion for *free*. And the same does not apply for the type `char`. Nonetheless, you can still use the generic [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), convert to a `String` and then again to array of chars:

```
  list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

> I want this so that later I can create a String using String(chars).
> Do we have any shortcuts using Stream?

Why not then do directly?!:

```
String collect = list.stream()
                     .map(String::valueOf)
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Running example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Character> list = List.of('H', 'e','l','l','o');
    String collect = list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static char[]  getCharArray(List<Character> charList) {
    return charList.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString()
        .toCharArray();
  }
```

Please do note this is constructing a `String`, which is backed by a char[] internally in Java. From the docs of `toCharArray()`

> Converts this string to a new character array.
>
> Returns: a newly
> allocated character array whose length is the length of this string
> and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence
> represented by this string.

So, This will internally create two char[] (One for backing String) and `toCharArray` returns a new Array with same content.

Comment: The `.map(String::valueOf)` step is obsolete. And since the OP said “I want this so that later I can create a String”, this solution can be made even more efficient by just omitting the `toCharArray()` and have the `String` already.

Answer (score 1):

*converting each* `Character` *to a* `String` *is incredible slow*
therefore so

```
int[] tmp = list.stream().mapToInt( c -> c ).toArray();
```

convert to a `String` only once

```
String rslt = new String( tmp, 0, tmp.length );
```

if You need the `char[]` too

```
char[] array = rslt.toCharArray();
```

*(what does someone need a* `List<Character>` *for?)*

Answer (score 0):

There is no special *`Stream`* method for converting `List<Character>` to an array of primitives `char[]`, but you can do it yourself with *`IntStream`*, for example:

```java
List<Character> list = List.of('a', 'b', 'c');

char[] chars = new char[list.size()];

IntStream.range(0, list.size()).forEach(i -> chars[i] = list.get(i));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars)); // [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it without Streams. Look at the method [toArray(T[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) of class List. It does exactly what you want. All you will need to do is:

```
Character[] charArray = charList.toArray(new Character[charList.size()]);
```

Comment: Can you try compiling it? `Character[]` is not the same as `char[]`.

Comment: Just a simple typo. changing the answer. But the method is still the right method to use

Comment: It’s a tenacious myth that passing `charList.size()` to the array was helping the performance. In fact, `charList.toArray(new Character[0])` is *more* efficient. If you are interested in details, you can read https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/

Comment: @Holger I don't understand why would someone have a `List<Character>`. Thoughts?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat you have to ask the questioner.